# Kubernetes Service IP Used for Node Application Listen... Error: listen EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I have a containerized node application that I am trying to transition to a K8s deployment from a docker deployment. I am currently running into an issue where the application tries to initiate the listener, but it uses the Service IP address instead of the Pod IP address, resulting in a listen EACCES permission denied error. Full error below:

```
[2023-10-06T17:54:20.365Z] [INFO]    Right before catastrophe
[2023-10-06T17:54:20.368Z] [INFO]    process exiting
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied tcp://10.105.58.16:8989
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1355:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1519:5)
    at Function.listen (/myservice/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
    at /myservice/index.js:108:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/myservice/index.js:12:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: 'tcp://10.105.58.16:8989',
  port: -1
}

Node.js v17.8.0
```

The 10.105.58.16 IP is for the K8s service, the Pod IP is 10.244.2.160.

I start node app listening with:

```
async function startServer(): Promise<void> {
  await createUncreatedTables();
  Log.info(`Right before catastrophe`);
  app.listen(config.get("port"), async () => {
    Log.info(`The ------------- is listening to ${config.get("port")}`);
    while (! await dbConfigured()) {
      //If the Db isn't configured wait 1 minute before retrying
      //note that if the DB isn't configured, the next non-log line will crash the program.
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 60 * 1000));
      await createUncreatedTables();
    }
    Log.info("DB configuration confirmed")

    Log.info("------------ Initialization Complete");
  });
}
```

I have a standard service that accepts on 8989 and forwards to 8989:

```
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8989
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8989
```

I've ensured that I've opened the container ports on the deployment as well

```
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8989
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
```

The pod is only in a CrashLoopBackoff while the service exists. If I manually delete the service and then recreate it after the pod has been able to pass it's health checks, routing works fine.

I tried to set the hostname parameter in app.listen to both 'localhost', and '127.0.0.1' to try to force it to use the pod IP, but ended with the same errors.

Comment: You want to listen to IP `0.0.0.0` in your container.

Comment: I've tried listening on 0.0.0.0 as well, it seems like any host/ip I pass into the app.listen command is ignored. 
`app.listen(config.get("port"), '0.0.0.0', async () => {xyz} )`
still gives me the eacces error on the service ip.